# transform - rotate and scale is not working when i convert html content to pdf

Tags: css, rotation, transform, scale, html2pdf

I am using html2pdf to convert HTML content with images to PDF and I have also added an option to rotate and flip the images...
Right now pdf is created successfully ... but if I have rotated or flipped any image by using CSS
`transform: rotate(90deg);`

```
transform:scaleX(-1);
```

then in a PDF file, that image is not looking rotated or flipped...
Any idea to get rid of this issue... Please share ...or any solution for that.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Perhaps html2pdf doesn't support the transform property.

Comment: Yes, i think u are right.. i just saw compatibility list from here
 http://www.tufat.com/docs/html2ps/compatibility.css.2.1.html
there is no details for transform...
Is there any way to do that..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

use "-webkit-transform" instead of "transform". for example:

```
 -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
```

Comment: Try using -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); along with -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

Answer (score 8):

try wkhtmltopdf, it works for css transforms also (but only with -webkit prefix)

https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

Comment: hi... i get a function _prepareTransform in html2pdf.class.php ....
but i have not ..how to use it?? or is wkhtmltopdf is able to convert html content with tranform : scale,rotate with lots of images...
i have googled many times but unfortunately i didn't get any thing... which can be helpfull for me...
thanks in advance...

Comment: i haven't used html2pdf so i don't have any idea about that..
wkhtmltopdf will convert html with any transform but i think you want to use it inside your code white wkhtmltopdf is a command line tool

Comment: thanks Yogesh for your info.. i will try to implement that...
could u please tell me .. why did you say that wkhtmltopdf works only with -webkit prefix. Is there any link or any example with some explanation : how to use it? can i implement it in localhost. Thanks..

Comment: because it uses webkit to render html. I think in the link given in answer, you can find everything you want. There is a wiki also where some examples are given even for integrating it with php. I used wkhtmltopdf using system/exec call in php to convert html to pdf.

Comment: @YogeshKhatri: for rails there is also a nice GEM, that wraps arround whhtml2pdf (wickedpdf). so you can use it like any format in rails. i.e. no command line. I just wanted to mention.

Answer (score 2):

try `style="-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);"` instead of transform.

It work for me in both **html-pdf** and **html2pdf** converter.

Answer (score 1):

I relaunch this old post.
For whom is still searching an alternative to wkhtmlToPdf or wkhtmlToImage that working with the lastest features of CSS3 and HTML5, here I found two tools thanks to this github issues :

https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/4092

So there is two awesome tools that simply use the Chromium browser directly, the one I use is **[Pupputer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer)** that allow you to use it though Node.js code (so it's a good thing for Node.js web server  !), taking a screenshot of the webpage and convert it to pdf or image.

**Also it allow you to choose your chromium based browser !!!** (Use puppeteer-core instead of puppeteer for the light version and using an external chromium)

I try it and it just render a screenshot that is the same as you can see it on your chromium browser, I use the `rotateX, rotateY, rotateZ` with `perspective` of CSS properties and working very well.

Enjoy !!!

> Puppeteer : https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer

> ChromeHtmlToPdf : https://github.com/Sicos1977/ChromeHtmlToPdf

Below a simple code to try it in your local side with Node.js :

```
// I use here the light version so I can choose my default chromium browser that I used on my Windows
    // to install it :
    // npm -i puppeteer-core
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');
    (async ()=>{
        // path to my default browser, idk if it's work with opera or other chromium based browser
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ executablePath: 'E:/Programmes/chrome-win/chrome.exe' });
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        
        // the default size if 800 * 600
        await page.setViewport({
            width: 800,
            height: 533,
            deviceScaleFactor: 1,
        });
        
        // the page targeted that I want the screenshot
        await page.goto('http://localhost/Fiverr/3dAxis/temp/2_photo2.jpg.html');
        
        // the output
        await page.screenshot({ path: 'example.png' });
        await browser.close();
    })();
```